# How can I have the index.html point to the correct path in the sub-location of a reverse proxy?

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

Currently the setup for Nginx looks about the following:

```
upstream docker-frontend-1 {
    server 0.0.0.0:8000;
}

upstream docker-frontend-2 {
    server 0.0.0.0:9000;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        // working
    }

    location /other-frontend/ {
        proxy_pass http://docker-frontend-2/other-frontend/;
        proxy_redirect http://docker-frontend-2 http://$lanIP$/other-frontend/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_connect_timeout 150;
        proxy_send_timeout 100;
        proxy_read_timeout 100s;
    }
}
```

Within the `index.html` for the second frontend, which runs inside a docker container, same as the first frontend, I have a referral to a script and stylesheet file as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/test.css" />
<script type="application/javascript" src="/js/test.js"></script>
```

However, now it tries to access these files on `example.com/js/test.css` and `example.com/js/test.js`, while they are located inside a different docker container than the first frontend. This docker container runs under `example.com/other-frontend/` as shown in the nginx configuration above.

This gives me the error of

> Refused to apply style from 'https://example.com/js/test.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

and

> Refused to execute script from 'https://example.com/js/test.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Which makes sense, since those files are indeed not located on that location, but inside the docker container which I reverse proxy into.

**My question** is, how could I make it so the stylesheets, scripts and other files are still called inside the appropriate docker container?

P.S. I cannot set up two DNS points for it, so it'll have to work like this and I cannot split anything up, so please leave those comments and suggestions outside of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why the problem is :**
This issue is happening because you mentioned the file paths of your docker container directly. And when the browser tries to load them, it will use the `domain` to concatenate with those files.

so if you try to load `/js/test.css` of docker container, it will use `www.example.com` ( as usual ) as the base URL to fetch and that's where the failure is.

There are so many answers to this question changing the backend, frontend, nginx configurations etc.

the **simplest fix** is :
adding `<base href="/other-frontend/">` inside the `<head>` tag of the HTML file you are rendering to `/other-frontend/` route.

Note : Add the above-mentioned tag **before to those script and link tags where you are importing your js and CSS files**

Comment: you actually brought me to an idea to grab the `.properties` file, update the `web.context=/other-frontend` and just run the docker while replacing those files with my custom files. This ended up working, thanks for the bright idea! :D